# Gifted money invested without tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, india, wire-transfer

If I gift $10k to my parents (parents are indian citizens, so am I) in India, and they use it to invest. Will that investment be taxed in USA? Taxed in india if kept long term? Is this a tax loop-hole for NRI to invest via Parents in India ?

Comment: What US tax are you concerned about? Are your parents US citizens? Are they investing is US securities?

Comment: "If I 'gift' money to my father, it should be from my understanding, 'his' money. " BS, pure and simple since **you** are thinking of your proposed scheme as a tax loophole whereby **you** can invest **via** parents and not pay any tax at all, either in India or in the US. Netiher a **gift** nor a **"gift"** has been made when you claim that you have made a gift to your parents.

Comment: My question is - is it a loophole or is it Illegal ? Either ways please send my some IRS URL, discouraging NRI's to do so.

Comment: There's no such link since most people understand that tax evasion is a crime. But if you need more specific details, start looking into terms "sham transaction", "fraudulent reports", "no economic substance" etc, because these will be used when the IRS will be bringing criminal charges against you. I also suggest talking to an attorney familiar with criminal prosecution of tax matters.

Comment: @littleadv informative, thanks for making me aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **you** are investing, via whoever you want, wherever you want, and you're a US tax resident - you **will** be taxed.

As with all the other questions, clearly your transfer of funds to your parents is not a real gift, and as such you will be keeping interest in the amounts. Income will be attributed to you, and taxes will also be charged to you. Having the money lie in your parents' accounts doesn't make the money or the income any less yours.

Comment: How and when do I need to report it for taxation? When stocks are sold? If my father sells stocks in India from his account, I pay tax is USA? Which form to fill?

Comment: Is it your father's money or yours? If it is your father's money then you have nothing to do with it whatsoever. If it is yours - it goes on your regular tax forms.

Comment: If I 'gift' money to my father, it should be from my understanding, 'his' money. Why should I pay tax if my gift is utilized for investing? Please point me to any URL with your explanation. Would be great help !

Comment: I can't wait to hear littleadv's response to this little gem of the OP's....

Comment: Only thing, I wish is an official documentation of government describing my situation, tax, and consequences. Would be very helpful

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I suggest you start looking in the 'criminal law' book under 'tax evasion' chapter.